# IntegrityError in djnago

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

Can't find a solution to this error please help or show me how to fix this.
The error is showing as follows:

(1048, "Column 'targetDefn_id' cannot be null") this error is showing when I post data.

This is my `views.py` in Post method I m getting this error:

```
def setTarget(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        print(data)
        serial=TargetSerializers(data=data)
        print(serial)
        if serial.is_valid():
            serial.save()
            print("done")
            return JsonResponse(serial.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK,safe=False)
        return JsonResponse(serial.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is my `Serializer.py` as follows:

```
class TargetSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    targetDefn=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    roleId=serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    empId=serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Target
        fields = (
            'id',
            'targetDefn',
            'roleId',
            'empId',
            'startDate',
            'endDate',
            'value'
        )

    def get_targetDefn(self,obj):
        trgt = TargetDefination.objects.get(id=obj.targetDefn_id)
        serial = TargetDefinationSerializers(trgt)
        return serial.data

    def get_empId(self,obj):
        emp= Employee.objects.get(id=obj.empId_id)
        serial= OnlyEmployeeSerializers(emp)
        return serial.data

    def get_roleId(self,obj):
        role=Role.objects.get(id=obj.roleId_id)
        serial=RoleSerializers(role)
        return serial.data
```

This is `models.py` as follows:

```
class Target(models.Model):
    targetDefn=models.ForeignKey(TargetDefination,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    roleId=models.ForeignKey(Role,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    empId=models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    startDate= models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    endDate= models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    value=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.empId) + ' ' +str(self.targetDefn)
```

Updated:
My Post query:

```
{
    "targetDefn": {
      "id": 1,
      "targetName": "MIN SALES",
      "displayName": "MIN SALES"
    },
    "roleId": {
      "id": 3,
      "roleName": "CIO",
      "description": "chief information officer",
      "roleReportsTo": 5,
      "roleReportsToName": "SeniorVP(M)"
    },
    "empId": {
      "id": 2,
      "empName": "Emp02",
      "startDate": "2021-04-01",
      "termDate": null
    },
    "startDate": "2021-05-11",
    "endDate": "2021-05-20",
    "value": "123"
  }
```

Comment: Can you add your POST query too ? the curl command for instance

Comment: @Romain I have added Post query.

Comment: @Romain Please help!

Comment: Is it possible that, because the `targetDefnId` is declared as a method field and not a model field, its data is not saved when performing the `serializer.save()` method (which essentialy calls the serializer `create/update` method. Maybe try overriding the `create` and `update`  method and correctly create the object with the `targetDefnId`

Comment: @JordanKowal can you explain with an example or sample code.

Comment: I've added a more detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

Know that the `SerializerMethodField` is `READ-ONLY`. It means that the data of those fields will not be written in the database. They will be computed and sent to your user, but never written in the DB. So, when you're saving your serializer, those fields are ignored.

I've noticed that you've created `SerializerMethodField` for all your foreign keys, only for their `get_[field]` method to return literally the serialized object. So why not simply use their nested-serializer right away?

```py
class TargetSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    targetDefn=TargetDefinationSerializers()
    roleId=OnlyEmployeeSerializers()
    empId=serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Target
        fields = (
            'id',
            'targetDefn',
            'roleId',
            'empId',
            'startDate',
            'endDate',
            'value'
        )
```

If you cannot get it to work or wish to keep your `SerializerMethodField` structure, then we must add the data of those 3 fields before saving. You can either pass the data as parameter in the serializer, like so:

```py
serializer.save(targetDefn=variable_1, roleId=variable_2, empId=variable_3)
```

Or you can override the `create` and `update` serializer methods to do it there, example:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
    targetDefn = validated_data["targetDefn"]
    roleId = validated_data["roleId"]
    emp_id = validated_data["emp_id"]
    # preprocess those data if needed
    # Then create your model
    Target.objects.create(targetDefn=targetDefn, ...)
```